# Measure performance of a VPS intended for hosting a website

Tags: performance, webserver

I just bought for a month an extremely cheap VPS with 16 GB RAM and 6 cores(from Contabo)

Now my question is, how can I get some benchmark results in order to compare it with other VPSes like Hostinger provides?

I did a Geekbench benchmark on it and the results can be seen here: https://browser.geekbench.com/v4/cpu/15852309

The problem with Geekbench is that I feel it's not really web oriented as the scores are influenced by the GPU as well.

What should I use in order to compare the VPSes between them?
Would the plan be enough to host a Magento 2 website / possibly more?

Comment: This question is better suited for https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For webserver performance the Network, Disk (random read) and CPU performance are the most important factors.

I like to benchmark and compare each one separately.

For **Disk I/O** performance, can use `sysbench`:

```
apt install sysbench
sysbench fileio --file-num=4 prepare
sysbench fileio --file-num=4 --file-test-mode=rndrw run
```

For **CPU** performance can use `stress-ng`:

```
apt install stress-ng
stress-ng -t 5 -c 2 --metrics-brief
```

`-c 2` uses 2 logical processors. Adjust if necessary.

For **network** performance can use `speedtest-cli`:

```
apt install speedtest-cli
speedtest-cli
```

Example output:

```
# sysbench fileio --file-num=4 --file-test-mode=rndrw run
<skip>

Throughput:
    read, MiB/s:                  45.01
    written, MiB/s:               30.00

# stress-ng -t 5 -c 2 --metrics-brief
stress-ng: info:  [14993] dispatching hogs: 2 cpu
stress-ng: info:  [14993] successful run completed in 5.00s
stress-ng: info:  [14993] stressor       bogo ops real time  usr time  sys time   bogo ops/s   bogo ops/s
stress-ng: info:  [14993]                           (secs)    (secs)    (secs)   (real time) (usr+sys time)
stress-ng: info:  [14993] cpu                3957      5.00      9.99      0.00       790.92       396.10

# speedtest-cli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from <skip> ...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Uganda Hosting Limited (Helsinki) [0.20 km]: 1.807 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 575.68 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed................................................................................................
Upload: 499.89 Mbit/s
```